# error while trying to parse xml stored in array in perl

Tags: perl

I have a following program but for some reason it is throwing an error and not parsing the xml file.

```
 my @findxmls;
 foreach my $searchxml(keys %xmlhash) {
 @findxmls= `find -name $findxml -maxdepth 4`;
 print Dumper (@findxmls);
```

up to this point works fine. it prints out all the xml files with the path.

```
 example of output
  y:\dir\subdir\procedure.xml
  y:\dir\otherdir\java.xml
```

but it does not work if i try to parse it

```
  foreach my $output (@findxmls) {                          
  my $parsexml = new XML::Simple;
      my $xmldata = $parser->XMLin($output );
  print Dumper ($xmldata);  
  }
```

ERROR

```
File does not exist: y:/dir/subdir/procedure.xml at sample.pl line 20
```

Comment: You should supply at least one actual file name or a part of the real output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backticks include newlines (`\n`) in the output, so the contents of your `@findxmls` array all have newlines on them. Change your script to either

```
chomp( @findxmls= `find -name $findxml -maxdepth 4` );
```

or

```
foreach my $output (@findxmls) {   
    chomp( $output );
    ...
}
```

Comment: ehh, thanks. one more question would you recommend using chomp all the time ?

Comment: use `chomp` when you expect your input to have newlines -- say from backticks or reading from a filehandle -- and you want the input not to have newlines.